# Sum of series question: $S_n = 1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16 + 1/25 + … + 1/n^2 < 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation

Prove that for any nonzero natural $n$ it is true that $$S_n = 1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16 + 1/25 + … +  1/n^2 < 2.$$

I'm sort of at a loss here. I'm not sure if there exists some formula or method to sum this kind of series, since there is a variable ratio…

Comment: Please do not post in the imperative.  If you have a question, please ask.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: You don't seem to have a series...

Comment: Moreover, your statement is clearly false: for example, if $n=1$ then your inequality does not hold.

Comment: People are answering a question that is not the one asked... (or, the challenge posed, rather)

Comment: @Mariano.  You are right.  I have deleted my posts.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174828/a-probably-trivial-induction-problem-sum-2nk-2-lt1) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220203/proving-1-frac14-frac19-cdots-frac1n2-leq-2-frac1n-for).

Comment: Well if 1 + 1/4 + ..... + 1/n^2 < 2 - 1/n^1 then 1+1/4 + ..... + 1/n^2 + 1/(n+1)^2 < 2 - 1/n^2 + 1/(n+1)^2 = 2 +(-(n+1)^2/n^2(n+1)^2 + n^2/(n+1)^2)= 2 +(-2n - 1)/(n+1)^2n^2 < 2 - 1/(n+1)^2$.  So it follows by induction.

Answer (score 12):

For $n>1$, a formula that will help is $$\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}.$$  This gives a telescoping series as an upper bound.

Comment: So I should just take the limit of (1/(n-1) - 1/n) as n approaches infinity?

Comment: No, you should see what happens if you use this upper bound.  For example, $1+\frac{1}{4}<1+1-\frac{1}{2}$.  $1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}<1+1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}$.  Simplify, continue the pattern and see what develops.  You may also want to search for references to telescoping series.

Answer (score 5):

you can compare with $1+\int_1^{\infty}n^{-2}$ (draw a picture) which is exactly $2$.  then estimate any little bit of the error to get below $2$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If you replace the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ terms after the first with the greater $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$, you can use partial fractions and telescope the series.  Alternately, there are difficult proofs that your series sums to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}\approx 1.64493 \lt 2$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the bound $\dfrac{1}{n^2} < \dfrac{1}{n-1} - \dfrac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, 2^n>(n+1)^2 for n large enough, so this does not bound the series.

Comment: Oh my gosh - you're right! Instead, consider the classic telescopic series! I'll edit my post.

Comment: @user: I should also note that you should check [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2) for methods of actually calculating the series.